# Exactamente donde abrir conexiones a base de datos en c#

Tags: c#

Hola gente como andan? tengo el siguiente código:

```
private void ActualizarStock()
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvFacturacion.Rows)
            {
                conexion.abrir();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select cant_art from detalle_compra Where id_compra = @id AND id_art = @idart", conexion.Conectarbd);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", txtNFactura.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idart", row.Cells["IDArticulo"].Value.ToString());
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    string stock = row.Cells["Cantidad"].Value.ToString(); //VALOR A MODIFICAR.
                    int a = int.Parse(dr["cant_art"].ToString());  //VALOR QUE ESTABA EN LA BASE DE DATOS.
                    conexion.cerrar();
                    int b = int.Parse(stock);
                    int resto = b - a;
                    conexion.cerrar();
                    UpdateStockArticulo(resto , row.Cells["IDArticulo"].Value.ToString());  
                } 
            }
            conexion.cerrar();
        }
        private void UpdateStockArticulo(int r , String b) {

            conexion.abrir();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT stock from articulo where idArticulo = @id", conexion.Conectarbd);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", b);
            SqlDataReader dr2 = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            conexion.cerrar();
            if (dr2.Read())
            {
                int a = int.Parse(dr2["stock"].ToString());
                a = r + a;
                conexion.abrir();
                SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("UPDATE articulo SET stock = @stock Where idArticulo = @id", conexion.Conectarbd);
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stock",a.ToString());
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", b);
                cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("ACTULIZADO EL STOCK.");
                conexion.cerrar();
            }
            conexion.cerrar();
        }
```

y no me funciona. Porque muestra una excepción de conexión, que ya existe una abierta. No conozco muy bien donde abrir cada conexión y cerrarla. Y ante estos dos métodos medios largos, me enrede. Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Saludos. No incluyes el mensaje de error tal cual se te presenta; y no indicas en que línea sale ese error. Ahora bien; revisando tu código me aventuro a decir es en el `foreach` que ocurre; no debes invocar `conexion.abrir();` dentro de este; sino antes de entrar en ese ciclo.

Comment: **'Intento no válido de llamar a Read cuando el lector está cerrado.'**
Linea:  **if (dr2.Read())**

Answer (score 0):

Cuando tu ejecutas un código de SQL, como es un select, update, delete, etc., siempre tienes que inicializar tu conexion (la variable de tipo SqlConnection) con un metodo llamado Open, y al ejecutar tu codigo o despues del SqlCommand, SqlDataAdaptert,la conexion se cierra con el metodo Close.
Te dejo un ejemplo si es que no me entendiste:

```
#region Variables Globales
SqlConnection consql = new SqlConnection("connection String") ;
SqlCommand comando;
// nvoalumno es un objeto de tipo alumno, puede ser cualquier parametro
 public int crear(Alumnos nvoalumno)
        {
            int agregado = 0;
            try
            {
                using(consql)
                {
                    //abres la conexion 
                    consql.Open();
                    //ejecuta el comando
                    comando = new SqlCommand(string.Format("Insert into Alumno(boleta,nombre)"+"values('{0}','{1}')",nvoalumno.boleta,nvoalumno.nombre),consql);
                    // Si no hubo algun error en sql te manda un 0 en caso contrario un 1
                    agregado = comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    //cierras la conexion
                    consql.Close();
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            return agregado;
        }
#endregion
```

Answer (score 0):

El momento en que se abre y cierra una conexión básicamente es abrirla antes de ejecutar una Sentencia SQL (sea llamada a SP, Select, Update, etc) y se cierra al momento que ya no se haran las operaciones en la base de datos.

**Cuando realizar una operación**

1. Abres conexión.
2. Preparas sentencia.
3. Ejecutas sentencia.
4. Se obtiene información (opcional).
5. Cierras conexión.

> El paso *4* se realiza si hay información por obtener.

**Extraer diversas filas (un `SELECT`)**

1. Abres conexión.
2. Preparas sentencia `SELECT`.
3. Ejecutas sentencia y su resultado lo colocas en un `SqlDataReader` (lo llamaremos `dr`).
4. Hace ciclo `while(dr.read())` y realizas la(s) acciones que correspondan dentro del mismo.
5. Fuera del `while` Cierras conexión.

> El paso 4 se repite hasta haber recorrido todas las filas.

**Mismo `SELECT` cambiando condición (un `foreach` y dentro de este un `while`)**

1. Obtienes el elemento del cual obtendrás lo que usaras para completar el `select`.
2. Aquí realizas **Extraer diversas filas (un `SELECT`)**

> Los pasos 1 y 2 se repiten hasta que el `foreach` a recorrido todos los elementos.

Con lo anterior podrás ver que (de tu planteamiento inicial) cierras las conexiones cuando aún las vas a usar.